# Should examples for functions be unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm writing a python function to replace all the non-alphanumeric characters in the keys of this dictionary with underscores.

To make sure it's working as expected as I don't have a ton of experience in the language, I created a sample dictionary with a few different samples to make sure it worked well enough.

Is this the kind of thing that would go into a unit test? Once I have it working is there any point to preserving this? And if so, would test driven development have been creating the sample dictionary and expected outcome first before writing the function?

Comment: Yes. Yes and yes.

Comment: You may want to consider using the https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/doctest.html module too as a fairly light-weight mechanism for simple tests.

Comment: Commit the [unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) to source control. Then add a [hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis) test to see if your "bug free!" assessment holds up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this the kind of thing that would go into a unit test?

Absolutely. Since I guess you used this sample dictionary for manual testing so far, I assume you did not necessarily implement a verification of the expected outcome - that is the part one will have to add here to make it a unit test.

> Once I have it working is there any point to preserving this?

Well, if there is a point to preserve the function you have written, and probably maintain and evolve it, such a unit test will become extremely useful. Only if you don't intent to maintain the function (because you know it will be used once and then never again, or because you know it will be replaced next week by something else), then it is questionable if keeping test data is worth the effort.

> And if so, would test driven development have been creating the sample dictionary and expected outcome first before writing the function?

Roughly speaking, yes. In TDD "by the book", one would probably start with a very tiny dictionary (maybe with just one key), implement a verification, then implement the function until the point it works correctly with this first sample. Then one would

- extend the dictionary
- run the tests (to see they fail),
- extend the function to make it work with the extended dictionary
- run the tests (to see that they do not fail any more)
- clean up / refactor the function
- and run the tests again (to verify the refactoring did not break anything).

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.
No, because test-driven development encourages creating test cases for each of the stories before implementation is started- at least it must forward development: not test checks implementation, but implementation satisfy uses stories as test cases. And this is not interrelated to examples or manuals.
Yes, because each test is an example itself (not vice versa).
But the test and example have different reasons, so finally- no.